# Using Projections on Formula Properties

Tags: sql, oracle, properties, formula, projection

I have a property in my XML mapping file like

```
<property name="CreatedByLogin"  formula="(select x.fst_name || ' ' || x.last_name from sebl_dev.S_CONTACT x where x.ROW_ID=CREATED_BY)" type="String" />
```

and I want to use a projection on this particular name like

```
.Add(Projections.Property("CreatedByLogin"), "CreatedByLogin")
```

and I do get Oracle exception.

Is there a way to do projection on a property that is declared using a formula?

My generated SQL is

```
select
     *
from (
     SELECT
         this_.ROW_ID as y0_,
         this_.CREATED as y1_,
         this_.CREATED_BY as y2_,
         this_.STATUS as y3_,
         this_.PSR_NUM as y4_,
         this_.ORDER_ID as y5_,
         this_.WFM_ID as y6_,
         this_.VIRTUAL_SS_ID as y7_,
         this_.VERIFIED_WITH as y8_,
         this_.REQ_DUE_DATE as y9_,
         this_.TYPE as y10_,
         account1_.NAME as y11_,
         account1_.OU_NUM as y12_,
         this_.DESCRIPTION as y13_,
         account1_.MARKET_TYPE_CD as y14_,
         account1_.X_SALES_CHANNEL as y15_,
         this_.QUOTE_ID as y16_,
         (
            select
                 x.fst_name || ' ' || x.last_name
            from sebl_dev.S_CONTACT x
            where x.ROW_ID=this_.CREATED_BY)
         as y17_,
         (
            select
                 x.fst_name || ' ' || x.last_name
            from sebl_dev.S_CONTACT x
            where x.ROW_ID=this_.LAST_UPD_BY)
         as y18_,
         serviceacc2_.INTEGRATION_ID as y19_,
         serviceacc2_.NAME as y20_,
         accountadd3_.ADDR as y21_,
         accountadd3_.ADDR_LINE_2 as y22_,
         accountadd3_.CITY as y23_,
         accountadd3_.STATE as y24_,
         accountadd3_.ZIPCODE as y25_
        FROM XOOE.XO_SS_HEADER this_
inner join XOOE.XO_SS_DETAILS this_1_
on this_.ROW_ID=this_1_.ROW_ID
 inner join sebl_dev.S_ORG_EXT account1_
on this_.CUST_ACCNT_ID=account1_.ROW_ID
left outer join sebl_dev.S_org_ext_x account1_1_
on account1_.ROW_ID=account1_1_.Row_id
 left outer join sebl_dev.S_ORG_EXT_UTX account1_2_
on account1_.ROW_ID=account1_2_.PAR_ROW_ID
inner join sebl_dev.S_ORG_EXT serviceacc2_ on this_.SERV_ACCNT_ID=serviceacc2_.ROW_ID
 left outer join sebl_dev.S_org_ext_x serviceacc2_1_
 on serviceacc2_.ROW_ID=serviceacc2_1_.Row_id
left outer join sebl_dev.S_ORG_EXT_UTX serviceacc2_2_
 on serviceacc2_.ROW_ID=serviceacc2_2_.PAR_ROW_ID
 inner join sebl_dev.S_ADDR_PER accountadd3_
on serviceacc2_.PR_ADDR_ID=accountadd3_.ROW_ID
        WHERE this_.TYPE = :p0 )

    where rownum <= :p1
```

and the resulting exception is

```
InnerException    {"ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table"}    System.Exception {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException}
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess:

you are selecting a key from a table that doesn't have key defined on it.  You are going to have to figure out which table it is, and add the primary key field to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Oracle versions 9, 10 and earlier versions of 11.  It is apparently fixed in the latest version.

The problem is caused by a bug in the way these older versions process SQL-92 style joins.  So if it is not possible to upgrade, you can work around them problem by using old style SQL-89 joins.  For example, an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT column
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.pk = t2.fk
```

Another example, this time for LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT column
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.pk = t2.fk(+)
```

More info:

http://awads.net/wp/2007/06/14/when-ansi-sql-join-syntax-does-not-work-in-oracle/